# Use of undeclared type 'CoreDataManager'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I've built a app and have decided to use CoreData so have had to retrospectively add it as opposed to ticking the Use CoreData option when first creating the project.

I believe I have everything after trying to follow several tutorials but have not been able to debug one error I'm getting.

I have a UiTableViewController that is using a FetchRequest to populate it's tableview. The code for the view has...

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class MileageLogsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var milageLogTableView: UITableView!

    var coreDataManager: CoreDataManager = CoreDataManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        do {
            try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        } catch {
            let fetchError = error as NSError
            print("Unable to Save MileageLog")
            print("\(fetchError), \(fetchError.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

The error appears against the line

```
var coreDataManager: CoreDataManager = CoreDataManager()
```

The error I get is Use of undeclared type 'CoreDataManager

The var is used late in the same class

```
private lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {
    // Initialize Fetch Request
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MileageLog")

    // Add Sort Descriptors
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "tripDate", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    // Initialize Fetched Results Controller
    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.coreDataManager.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    return fetchedResultsController
}()
```

Any help on how to fix/debug this error would be appreciated.

Comment: What is CoreDataManager? it is not part of CoreData so have you created that somewhere?

Comment: The error you are getting Use of undeclared type `CoreDataManager` is nothing to do with `NSFetchedResultsController`

Comment: My bad! I've been following several tutorials and there was a lump of code that one tutorial had within AppDelgate Class. In the other tutorial the same code was shown but I hadn't spotted that this tutorial had the data in it's own class called CoreDataManager. As soon as I moved the code into it's own class the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad! I've been following several tutorials and there was a lump of code that one tutorial had within AppDelgate Class. In the other tutorial the same code was shown but I hadn't spotted that this tutorial had the data in it's own class called CoreDataManager. As soon as I moved the code into it's own class the error disappeared.